# Possible to achieve `ScrollView` interactive keyboard dismissal in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/keyboarddismissmode/interactive

On a typical `UIScrollView`, **one may set this property** to have the keyboard dismiss interactively alongside a scroll.

Is it possible to achieve this in SwiftUI? If it’s not directly available on `ScrollView`, I assume it’s perhaps possible by embedding a `UIScrollView` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `SwiftUI` documentation it doesn't seem like this is possible yet. I think your best option would be to wrap an `UIScrollView` into an `UIViewRepresentable` see [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/) for the dev talk. I found a [tutorial for a UIScrollView here](https://www.appsdissected.com/missing-features-swiftui-uiviewrepresentable-wrap-uikit-controls/) you will just need to add the `KeyboardDismissmode` to the code

Answer (score 13):

I add the code in my ContentView's onAppear modifier. It can be `onDrag` or `.interactive` depends on when you want to dismiss keyboard:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .onAppear {
                UITableView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that if the Emoji keyboard is shown and you slide the emojis, this causes the keyboard to hide weirdly - any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: @hyouuu For me, I was trying to dismiss keyboard on 'List' so I used UITableView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag to prevent emoji keyboard from dismissing.

Comment: @SteveHam Thanks for your suggestion. Let me update my answer so other people won't have that bug anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Yes,

add this code to init()

```swift
init() {
    // on a list:
    // UITableView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    UIScrollView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've even added this code to AppDelegate. I guess nowadays it is the default expected keyboard behaviour.

Comment: This does not work when we try to slide down the emoji keyboard

Answer (score 7):

Also want to point out that [jsbeginnerNodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11411002/jsbeginnernodejs)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057578/616764) also works on *any* scrollable view, such as `List`. For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = GistsViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchBar(text: $viewModel.searchText)

                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.gists) { gist in
                        NavigationLink(destination: SafariView(url: gist.htmlURL)
                            .navigationBarTitle("")
                            .navigationBarHidden(true)) {
                                GistView(gist: gist)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("GitHub Gists"))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        UIScrollView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still struggling with this.

As @yawnobleix mentioned there isn't any built-in modifier on `ScrollView` to achieve that on iOS <16.0

Assigning UITableView appearance to the whole app is not always the best option, so I find another one using `DragGesture`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // your content
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged { _ in
            endEditing()
        })
    }
}

extension View {
    func endEditing(_ force: Bool = true) {
        UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { $0.endEditing(force)}
    }
}
```

**SwiftUI 4.0**

Finally, Apple add [ScrollDismissesKeyboardMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrolldismisseskeyboardmode) modifier to `ScrollView`.
So you can simply add

```
.scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively) //iOS 16.0 or newer
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, please refer to https://github.com/michaelhenry/KeyboardAvoider

Either wrap the view inside “KeyboardAvoider {}”

Or

Use the ViewModifier “.avoidKeyboard()”

Answer (score 0):

For those who's using SwiftUI 'List' and want to dismiss keyboard, use below instead. UIScrollView dismisses keyboard on emoji keyboard horizontal scroll.

```
UITableView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```